# Using apply for simulation instead of nested for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation, apply

I reproduced in R a simulation that was originally done in Stata. I used 'for' loops since this is the only way I know how to make this work. It takes quite a long time to run, so I would like to use one of the 'apply' commands instead to see if it's faster, yet I can't figure out how to do it. Can anybody help? Here's the code:

```
simdiffuse <- function(a, b, c, d) {

  endo <- 1/a        # innovation endogenous effect
  endomacro <- 1/b   # category endogenous effect
  appeal <- c        # innovation's ex ante appeal
  ninnov <- d        # number of innovations in category 

  results <- data.frame(catdensity = rep(0:ninnov, each = 25), t = 1:25, endo = endo, endomacro = endomacro, appeal = appeal, adopt = NA)    

  prop <- rnorm(1000)
  diff <- data.frame(prop)
  diff$adopt <- 0
  diff$adopt[1:5] <- 1

  for (catdensity in 0:ninnov) {
    diff$adopt <- 0
    diff$adopt[1:5] <- 1

    for (t in 1:25) {
      results[results$catdensity == catdensity & results$t == t,]$adopt <- mean(diff$adopt)
      for (obs in 1:nrow(diff)) {
        if(appeal+(mean(diff$adopt)*endo)+(catdensity*endomacro) > rnorm(1, diff[obs,]$prop)) diff[obs,]$adopt <- 1
      }
    }
  }
  return(results)
}

results <- simdiffuse(.2, 20, -3, 60)
```

Comment: `apply` family functions are not necessarily faster than a for loop. Slowness in the loop is often from growing your array or matrix or whatever within the loop rather than pre-allocating an object of the correct size. Have you tried running [Rprof](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/Rprof.html) to see where your code is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve the speed of your function by using `data.table`. However, you would still have to use `for` loops (which is not a bad thing).

```
library(data.table)
simdiffuse <- function(a, b, c, d) {

  endo <- 1/a        # innovation endogenous effect
  endomacro <- 1/b   # category endogenous effect
  appeal <- c        # innovation's ex ante appeal
  ninnov <- d        # number of innovations in category 

  results <- data.table(catdensity = rep(0:ninnov, each = 25), t = 1:25, 
                        endo = endo, endomacro = endomacro, appeal = appeal, 
                        adopt = as.numeric(NA))    


  for (cc in 0:ninnov) {
    diff <- data.table(prop = rnorm(1000), adopt = c(rep(1,5), rep(0, 995)))
    for (tt in 1:25) {
      results[catdensity == cc & t == tt, adopt := diff[, mean(adopt)]]
      diff[, rr := rnorm(1, prop), by="prop"]
      diff[appeal + mean(adopt) * endo + cc * endomacro > rr, adopt := 1]
    }
  }
  return(results)
}

results <- simdiffuse(.2, 20, -3, 60)
```

I did not have enough time to wait until your code is executed, but here is a graph of `adopt` vs. `t` that I get:

[image: adopt vs. t, grouped by catdensity]

Comment: Thanks for this. I was struggling with the idea that I had to use one of the `apply` functions, so it is good to know that that is not the case, and to see another way in which I can try to improve the speed of my code.